# Tikz: Draw simplified BLE-Stack

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

Can anyone give me an example how to draw this BLE-Stack with tikz?

[image: BLE-Stack]

**EDIT**

Now, I'm very close to my wished result :)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,>=latex',font=\sffamily]
\tikzstyle{Dotted} = [draw=black,dashed,thick,rectangle,minimum width=120mm,minimum height=33mm]
\tikzstyle{Normal} = [draw=black,thick,rectangle,minimum width=108mm,minimum height=12mm]
\node[label=left:Controller,label={[label distance=5.5mm]},Dotted](Controller){};
\node[above left = 3mm and 6mm of Controller.south east,anchor=south east,Normal](PHY){LE Physical Layer\\(PHY)};
\node[above = 3mm of PHY,Normal](LL){Link Layer\\(LL)};
\node[above = 10mm of Controller.north west,anchor=north west](HCI0){};
\node[above = 10mm of Controller.north east,anchor=north east](HCI1){};
\draw[dash pattern={on 5mm off 3mm},line width=1.2mm,](HCI0) -- (HCI1) node[midway,fill=white]{Host Controller Interface\\(HCI)};
\node[above = 18mm of Controller,label=left:Host,label={[label distance=5.5mm]},Dotted,minimum height=48mm](Host){};
\node[above left = 3mm and 6mm of Host.south east,anchor=south east,Normal](L2CAP){Logical Link Control and Adaption Protocol\\(L2CAP)};
\node[above =15mm of L2CAP.north east,anchor=north east,Normal,minimum width=51mm](ATT){Attribute Protocol\\(ATT)};
\node[above = 15mm of ATT.east,anchor=east,Normal,minimum width=51mm](GATT){Generic Attribute Profile\\(GATT)};
\node[above = 15mm of L2CAP.north west,anchor=north west,Normal,minimum width=51mm](GAP){Generic Access Profile\\(GAP)};
\node[above = 15mm of GAP.north west,anchor=north west,Normal,minimum width=51mm](SMP){Security Manager Protocol\\(SMP)};
\node[above = 3mm of Host,label=left:Application,label={[label distance=5.5mm]},Normal,minimum width=120mm](Application){Application\\(APP)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code results in this output

[image]

There are just two questions:

1. How to start the dashed line from the left border and from the right to get a symmetrical dashed line?
2. How to delete the insertion on the left and right of the dashed line?

Comment: what you try so far?

Comment: This should not be so difficult. You only need to draw nodes, write in it their text and than positioned in image. For example: \node (PHY) [draw, minimum width=21em,align=center] {LE Physical Layer (PHI)};˙for the bottom box (where `(PHY)` is name of node. for the next node is the almost the same, you onlky need to ad option `above=of PHY`. Of course it would be very helpful to read `tikz` documentation.

Comment: Give me some time, I'm preparing something

Comment: @Raaja please let OPs time to react! What is the advantage to close so fast? Please retract your close vote!

Comment: I edited my question with my solution!

Comment: Please, add a compileable code that starts with`\documentclass{}`and ends with `\end{document}`

Comment: @AndréC Did it!

Comment: For the dash pattern `\path[](HCI0) -- (HCI1) node[midway,fill=white](aux){Host Controller Interface\\(HCI)};
\draw [dash pattern={on 5mm off 3mm},line width=1.2mm](aux)--(HCI0)(aux)--(HCI1);`

Comment: I didn't understand what your second problem is.

Comment: Perfect! First question is solved. The other question aims to the gap between the 'virtual' left and right border and the starting point of the dashed line.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the large dotted lines to be on a line as large as the width of the box drawn in small dotted lines, is that right?

Comment: yes thats right.

Comment: If you keep the current settings of the large dotted line, the last dotted line will be cut (smaller). So, you have to find a combination (`on ...mm off ...mm`) that makes exactly the desired width. This deserves a second question in its own right because it is already much more complicated.

Comment: It was a misunderstanding due to how the question was presented in the review queue. I have deleted the comment, and will revert the closing vote if I find a way to do that. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything here is placed with respect to the components in the diagram. With the comments, the logic is very easy to follow.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
  nopadding/.style={
    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt
  },
  textBlock/.style={
    draw, text width=12em, text centered, minimum height=2em,
    nopadding, inner ysep=3pt
  },
  longTextBlock/.style={
    text width=24em, text centered, minimum height=2em,
    nopadding, inner ysep=3pt
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small\sffamily]%
    \node[draw=none,minimum width=25em, nopadding] (start) at (0,0) {}; % Starting point
    % Host
    % Row 1, col 1
    \node[textBlock, below=of start.south west, anchor=west]
         (SMP){Security Manager Protocol\\(SMP)};
    % Row 1, col 2
    \node[textBlock, below=of start.south east, anchor=east]
         (GATT){Generic Attribute Profile\\(GATT)};
    % Row 2, col 1
    \node[textBlock, below of=SMP](GAP){Generic Access Profile\\(GAP)};
    % Row 2, col 2
    \node[textBlock, below of=GATT](ATT){Attribute Protocol\\(ATT)};
    % Row 3, col 1&2
    \node[fit=(SMP) (GATT), below=of GAP.west, anchor=west, draw, nopadding](L2CAP){};
    % Row 3, col 1&2 text
    \node[longTextBlock] 
         (L2CAPText)at(L2CAP.center){Logical Link Control and Adaption Protocol\\(L2CAP)};
    % Host dashed line and label
    \node[fit=(L2CAP) (SMP) (GAP) (GATT) (ATT), 
         draw, dashed, label={[black, xshift=-5pt]left:Host} ](hostFit){};
    % Application label
    \node[fit=(hostFit.west) (hostFit.east)(GAP), 
         above=of hostFit.north west, anchor=north west,
         draw, nopadding, label={[black, xshift=-5pt]left:Application}](appFit){};
    % Application text
    \node[longTextBlock] (appText) at (appFit.center){Application\\(APP)};
    % Controller dashed lines fit
    \node[fit=(hostFit.west) (hostFit.east)(GAP), 
         below=of hostFit.south west, anchor=south west,
         nopadding,draw=none](controllerDashed){};
    % Controller actual lines and text.
     \draw[dash pattern={on 7pt off 3pt}, line width=3pt]
         (controllerDashed.west) -- (controllerDashed.east)
         node[textBlock, midway,fill=white, draw=none]
         {Host Controller Interface\\(HCI)};
    % Controller
    % Row 1
    \node[fit=(L2CAP), below=of controllerDashed.south, anchor=south, 
         nopadding, draw, yshift=-5pt](controllerRow1){};
    % Row 1 text
    \node[longTextBlock] 
         (controlRow1Text) at (controllerRow1.center){LE Physical Layer\\(PHY)};
    % Row 2
    \node[fit=(controllerRow1), below of = controllerRow1, draw, 
         nopadding,draw](controllerRow2){};
    % Row 2 text
    \node[longTextBlock] 
    (controlRow2Text) at (controllerRow2.center){Link Layer\\(LL)};
    % Controller dashed lines and label
    \node[fit=(controllerRow1)(controllerRow2), draw, dashed, 
         label={[black, xshift=-5pt]left:Control}](controlFit){};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

With use of TikZ libraries `fit` and `positioning`, for all positioning distances are used only values defined in `node distance`. This enables to write clear, concise and consistent code:

**Edit:**
if you like to change distances of nodes' labels from nodes (on consistent way), you only need to add `label distance  = <desired amount>` to `tikzpicture` options (added now to MWE below.

Also, if you like to change distance between nodes and doted nodes around it, for example have different in horizontal direction from vertical, you only need to add `inner xsep` and `inner ysep` in style for node `FIT`. For example:

```
FIT/.style = {draw, semithick, dotted, fit=#1,
              inner xsep=4mm, inner ysep=2mm},  % here you can adjust inner distance of node},
```

All aforementioned I now added to my MWE.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 0mm,
   box/.style = {draw, text width=#1, inner sep=2mm, align=center},
   box/.default = 98mm,
   FIT/.style = {draw, semithick, dotted, fit=#1,
                 inner xsep=4mm, inner ysep=2mm},  % here you can adjust inner distance of node
                                                   % this adjust you need to consider at defining the width of the top nodes
label distance = 2mm,
      font = \sffamily
                        ]
\node (phy) [box]                   {LE Physical Layer\\(PHY)};
\node (lll) [box, above = of phy]   {Link Layer\\(LL)};
    \node (cntrl) [FIT=(phy) (lll), label=left:Control] {};
%
\node (hci) [box=12em,draw=none, 
             above=of cntrl]        {Host Controller Interface\\(HCI)};
\draw[line width=1.2mm, dash pattern=on 5mm off 3mm]  % solve your first question
    (lll.west |- hci) -- (hci)  
    (lll.east |- hci) -- (hci);
%
\node (cap) [box, above=of hci]     {Logical Link Control and Adaption Protocol\\(L2CAP)};
\node (gap) [box=44mm,
             above right=of cap.north west] {Generic Access Profile\\(GAP)};
\node (att) [box=44mm,
             above  left=of cap.north east] {Attribute Protocol\\(ATT)};
\node (smp) [box=44mm,
             above=of gap]          {Security Manager Protocol\\(SMP)};
\node (gap) [box=44mm,
             above=of att]          {Generic Attribute Profile\\(GATT)};
    \node (host) [FIT=(cap) (smp), label=left: Host] {};
%
\node (app) [box=106mm, above= of host,
             label=left:Application]        {Application\\(APP)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

1. For the first question, simply name the node where the text is written, then draw the pattern from this node to the edges.

```
    \path[](HCI0) -- (HCI1) node[midway,fill=white](aux){Host Controller Interface\\(HCI)};%<--- auxiliary node (aux)
    \draw [dash pattern={on 5mm off 3mm},line width=1.2mm](aux)--(HCI0)(aux)--(HCI1);% pattern from center to edges
```

2. The second question is more complex, so I suggest that you make it another question in its own right.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,>=latex',font=\sffamily]
\tikzstyle{Dotted} = [draw=black,dashed,thick,rectangle,minimum width=120mm,minimum height=33mm]
\tikzstyle{Normal} = [draw=black,thick,rectangle,minimum width=108mm,minimum height=12mm]
\node[label=left:Controller,label={[label distance=5.5mm]},Dotted](Controller){};
\node[above left = 3mm and 6mm of Controller.south east,anchor=south east,Normal](PHY){LE Physical Layer\\(PHY)};
\node[above = 3mm of PHY,Normal](LL){Link Layer\\(LL)};
\node[above = 10mm of Controller.north west,anchor=north west](HCI0){};
\node[above = 10mm of Controller.north east,anchor=north east](HCI1){};

% new node (aux)
\path[](HCI0) -- (HCI1) node[midway,fill=white](aux){Host Controller Interface\\(HCI)};%<--- auxiliary node (aux)
\draw [dash pattern={on 5mm off 3mm},line width=1.2mm](aux)--(HCI0)(aux)--(HCI1);% pattern from center to edges

\node[above = 18mm of Controller,label=left:Host,label={[label distance=5.5mm]},Dotted,minimum height=48mm](Host){};
\node[above left = 3mm and 6mm of Host.south east,anchor=south east,Normal](L2CAP){Logical Link Control and Adaption Protocol\\(L2CAP)};
\node[above =15mm of L2CAP.north east,anchor=north east,Normal,minimum width=51mm](ATT){Attribute Protocol\\(ATT)};
\node[above = 15mm of ATT.east,anchor=east,Normal,minimum width=51mm](GATT){Generic Attribute Profile\\(GATT)};
\node[above = 15mm of L2CAP.north west,anchor=north west,Normal,minimum width=51mm](GAP){Generic Access Profile\\(GAP)};
\node[above = 15mm of GAP.north west,anchor=north west,Normal,minimum width=51mm](SMP){Security Manager Protocol\\(SMP)};
\node[above = 3mm of Host,label=left:Application,label={[label distance=5.5mm]},Normal,minimum width=120mm](Application){Application\\(APP)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I add `\draw(current bounding box.south east) rectangle(current bounding box.north west);` to the end, I can see about 1 cm white space at the top of the tikz image. How can I reduce this space?

Comment: You can shift like this `\draw(current bounding box.south east) rectangle([shift={(0mm,-8mm)}]current bounding box.north west);`

Comment: Yes, but this is just a hack isn't it? I found out, that the white space is produced through my label definition `label=left:Host,label={[label distance=5.5mm]}`. If I activate draw labels I can see a label above the Host. Is there a way just to draw the left label and not the label above?

Comment: It is the syntax of TikZ coordinates that allows you to specify local options as described on page 133 of the 3.1.4b manual. I quote `The general syntax is ([<options>]coordinate specification).` This allows coordinates to be adjusted locally.

Comment: You can simplify your code by using styles as Mr. Al Jumaily and Zarko did in their answer. It is still heavy, but it is normal that it is for the first time. Using styles makes it easier to understand the code and maintain it over time.

Comment: I solved it now. I have to use `\node[above = 18mm of Controller,label={[label distance=3mm]left:Host},Dotted,minimum height=48mm](Host){};` and the label above will disappear.

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Once you have finalized your code. It is recommended on this site to answer your own question. Read: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 4):

This answer shows the differences between my first try solution in the question and my final solution. The differences are located in the label definitions, please see my comments.

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
% First try mentioned in the question
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,>=latex',font=\sffamily]
\tikzstyle{Dotted} = [draw=black,dashed,thick,rectangle,minimum width=120mm,minimum height=33mm]
\tikzstyle{Normal} = [draw=black,thick,rectangle,minimum width=108mm,minimum height=12mm]
\node[label=left:Controller,label={[label distance=5.5mm]},Dotted](Controller){};
\node[above left = 3mm and 6mm of Controller.south east,anchor=south east,Normal](PHY){LE Physical Layer\\(PHY)};
\node[above = 3mm of PHY,Normal](LL){Link Layer\\(LL)};
\node[above = 10mm of Controller.north west,anchor=north west](HCI0){};
\node[above = 10mm of Controller.north east,anchor=north east](HCI1){};
\draw[dash pattern={on 5mm off 3mm},line width=1.2mm,](HCI0) -- (HCI1) node[midway,fill=white]{Host Controller Interface\\(HCI)};
\node[above = 18mm of Controller,label=left:Host,label={[label distance=5.5mm]},Dotted,minimum height=48mm](Host){};
\node[above left = 3mm and 6mm of Host.south east,anchor=south east,Normal](L2CAP){Logical Link Control and Adaption Protocol\\(L2CAP)};
\node[above =15mm of L2CAP.north east,anchor=north east,Normal,minimum width=51mm](ATT){Attribute Protocol\\(ATT)};
\node[above = 15mm of ATT.east,anchor=east,Normal,minimum width=51mm](GATT){Generic Attribute Profile\\(GATT)};
\node[above = 15mm of L2CAP.north west,anchor=north west,Normal,minimum width=51mm](GAP){Generic Access Profile\\(GAP)};
\node[above = 15mm of GAP.north west,anchor=north west,Normal,minimum width=51mm](SMP){Security Manager Protocol\\(SMP)};
\node[above = 3mm of Host,label=left:Application,label={[label distance=5.5mm]},Normal,minimum width=120mm](Application){Application\\(APP)};
% Just to demonstrate the outlines
\draw(current bounding box.south east) rectangle(current bounding box.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}

% Second try with improved outlines
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,>=latex',font=\sffamily]
\tikzstyle{Dotted} = [draw=black,dashed,thick,rectangle,minimum width=120mm,minimum height=33mm]
\tikzstyle{Normal} = [draw=black,thick,rectangle,minimum width=108mm,minimum height=12mm]
% Edited label configuration
\node[label={[label distance=3mm]left:Controller},Dotted](Controller){};
\node[above left = 3mm and 6mm of Controller.south east,anchor=south east,Normal](PHY){LE Physical Layer\\(PHY)};
\node[above = 3mm of PHY,Normal](LL){Link Layer\\(LL)};
\node[above = 10mm of Controller.north west,anchor=north west](HCI0){};
\node[above = 10mm of Controller.north east,anchor=north east](HCI1){};
\path[](HCI0) -- (HCI1) node[midway,fill=white](aux){Host Controller Interface\\(HCI)}; 
\draw [dash pattern={on 5mm off 3mm},line width=1.2mm](aux)--(HCI0)(aux)--(HCI1);
% Edited label configuration
\node[above = 18mm of Controller,label={[label distance=3mm]left:Host},Dotted,minimum height=48mm](Host){};
\node[above left = 3mm and 6mm of Host.south east,anchor=south east,Normal](L2CAP){Logical Link Control and Adaption Protocol\\(L2CAP)};
\node[above =15mm of L2CAP.north east,anchor=north east,Normal,minimum width=51mm](ATT){Attribute Protocol\\(ATT)};
\node[above = 15mm of ATT.east,anchor=east,Normal,minimum width=51mm](GATT){Generic Attribute Profile\\(GATT)};
\node[above = 15mm of L2CAP.north west,anchor=north west,Normal,minimum width=51mm](GAP){Generic Access Profile\\(GAP)};
\node[above = 15mm of GAP.north west,anchor=north west,Normal,minimum width=51mm](SMP){Security Manager Protocol\\(SMP)};
% Edited label configuration
\node[above = 3mm of Host,label={[label distance=3mm]left:Application},Normal,minimum width=120mm](Application){Application\\(APP)};
% Just to demonstrate the outlines
\draw(current bounding box.south east) rectangle(current bounding box.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**RESULT**

- On the left: First try
- On the right: Final solution

[image]

Comment: Please, explain what id in your answer different from others, especial from accept one. From image i can only conclude, that you add borders around labels (what wasn't  demand in your question).

Comment: Sorry, beside to changed distance of labels `Controller`, `Host` and `Application` I don't  see any differences :-). that means that you add new size of label distance only ... you should mentioned this demand at least in comments below received answers ... see my edited answer. BTW, desired changes of received answers in form of last answer is not fer to people who prepare answers according to your question.

Comment: I primarily didn't want to answer my question but please see the comment below AndréC's answer. _Once you have finalized your code. It is recommended on this site to answer your own question._ [Read](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)  – AndréC